# Phaser State Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, facebook, phaser-framework, states

I am getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: login is not defined when I am attempting to add the login state.  I have added many other states without issues.

```
        //begin loading game
        var game = new Phaser.Game(width, height, Phaser.CANVAS, 'gameArea'); 


        game.state.add('boot', Boot);

        game.state.add('login',Login);
        game.state.add('level1',Level1);
        game.state.add('level2',Level2);
        game.state.add('level3',Level3);
        game.state.add('level4',Level4);
        game.state.add('level5',Level5);

        game.state.start('boot', true, false, 0);
```

And here is the login state code:

```
Login = function(game) {

    this.score;

};

Login.prototype = {

init: function(score){

    this.score = score;

},

preload: function() {


},

create: function() {


    var fb = Cocoon.Social.Facebook;  

    fb.init({
        appId:"#####",
        channelUrl: "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    });


    var socialService = fb.getSocialInterface();
    var loggedIn = socialService.isLoggedIn();


    if (!socialService.isLoggedIn()) {
        socialService.login(function(loggedIn, error) {
            if (error) {
                console.error("login error: " + error.message);
            }
            else if (loggedIn) {
                console.log("login succeeded");
                //this.fbLogIn.text = "Welcome, ";

                socialService.requestUser(function(user, error) {
                      if (error) {
                          console.error("requestUser error: " + error.message);
                      }
                       else {
                            console.log("You are " + user.userName + " " + user.userID);

                            game.state.start('boot',true,false,this.score,user.userID, user.userName);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("login cancelled");
                game.state.start('boot',true,false,this.score)
            }
        });
    }
  }

};
```

I have tried adding that state with the Login.js without the Facebook log in code, but I am still getting the same error.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: On what line is the problem occurring? Could it be at `socialService.login(...`?

Comment: @ShadowCat7 it is happening at  game.state.add('login',Login);

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `Login` as a variable before you use it. In your login state code:

```
var Login = function (game) {};
```

Comment: I did that and the same error appeared when running.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. it has to be initialized as well. Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-coding-tips/blob/master/issue-001/tanks.html) Phaser provides.